# React: Changing Screen.js to LandScape Orientation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, orientation, landscape

Hello I am new to React Native and I am trying to change this screen (gameScreen.js) to have Orientation to be landscape instead of being portrait. All the other screen I want to keep Orientation as portrait. So what can I do to change the orientation to Landscape for GameScreen.js.

The Image Below is what I have tried; however, the screen is not changing to landscape but instead throws an error stating "NULL is not an object (evaluating 'Orientation.lockToLandscape)".
I have tried using the library from 'react-native-orientation'; however, I have no clue on how to use them. Please HELP! Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is basically saying it does not recognise the react-native-orientation module. Make sure you follow the documentation to properly link the module as per https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation.

If you're new to React Native then [Expo](https://expo.io) might be of interest as it handles a lot of the pain of linking modules etc in favour of imports. In this instance: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/

Comment: Thank you for the expo Library :)  ScreenOrientation Library helped!
I utilized the function: ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE);

Which helped me change the screen to landscape.

Comment: Happy days! You're welcome :)

If think my answer solved your question could you please accept it?

Comment: Just did and Thank you again!